# How to create a search box like android.com website?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to create a search box like android website? when i click the search icon the menu items fade out and the search box expands.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nQJP.png)

[Before search and after clicking the search icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8H7S.png)

Comment: also add your code here

Answer (score 0):

i think you want somthing like this?
hope this is use full

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#im").click(function(){
   $("#menu").fadeOut();
   $("#box1").fadeIn();
  });
 });
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <div id="menu">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><img id="im" src="a.png" height="50px" width="50px"></li>
  </div>
  <li id="box1" style='display: none;'>
  <div class="box">
  <div class="container-1">
      <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
      <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." />
  </div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```